# I have a problem with Bootstrap grid system not changing the columns correctly according to pixel sizes specified on getbootstrap guidelines

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code that is supposed to make the columns collapse at the size of 991px but it keeps doing it at 767px, in otherwords I'm specifying that it should collapse when it's less than a medium device but it's only doing it when it's less than a small device, I checked my code many times and I'm confused as to what's going on since I'm following the exact code in my class, here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Starter Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">Col 1</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">Col 2</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">Col 3</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[See it's still treating it as 4 4 4 even though the size is below 991px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLRLn.png)

[And here it finally works at 767px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJZe0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I need to ask, what is all of the other code. Since the problem is 100% not in the HTML. (Just saying I am just putting this as an answer because I don't have the 50 reputation needed to add a comment on other people's questions.)